# Passing array elements between different classes in Java

Tags: java, arrays, element

I am having trouble passing the elements in an array that holds names and numbers to another class where calculations will be done. This is what I have for the classes.

```
public class Employee {
    private int sales;
    private String name;

    public Employee(String name, int sales){
        this.name = name;
        this.sales = sales;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public int getSales(){
        return this.sales;
    }
}
```

That class is to help store the name and sales for the array. Here is the array in its separate class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmployeeArray {

    public static int employee() {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int numEmp;
        System.out.println("Enter how may employees to be compared: ");
        numEmp = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        Employee[] employees = new Employee[numEmp];

        for (int i = 0; i < numEmp; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
            String employeeName = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Enter your annual sales: ");
            int employeeSales = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.println();

            Employee employee = new Employee(employeeName, employeeSales);
            employees[i] = employee;
        }
        Employee maxSeller = employees[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {

            System.out.println("Employee Name: " + employees[i].getName());
            System.out.println("Total sales: $" + employees[i].getSales());
            System.out.println();

            if (maxSeller.getSales() < employees[i].getSales()) {
                maxSeller = employees[i];
            }
        } 
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Top Seller is: " + maxSeller.getName());
        System.out.println("Top Sales are: $" + maxSeller.getSales());

        return maxSeller.getSales();

    }
}
```

The array holds the values and returns a top seller called maxSeller and gets the name and sales amount for them. Now the problem I am running into is that in a separate class I need to get the values stored in this array to do some calculations. I have to get sales of maxSeller and compare them to the sales of the other sellers in the array. Form there I am trying to display how much more sales the others need to get to equal or surpass the top seller. That is the problem I am running into. I don't know how to pass the values from this array to the next class so I can do the calculations. Any thoughts?

Comment: what is the separate class? You should pass the array of employees as a parameter to a method in whatever other class you create. From there you can access the sales or name with the getters

Comment: Questions like this often suggest a situation in which a procedurally-designed solution cannot be easily adopted to an object-oriented paradigm.  If you were to stop writing the solution to this like you were writing a BASIC program, and began thinking about the objects involved in your model and the behaviors you wanted those objects to implement, problems like "how do I pass arrays between procedures" become much less of an issue.

Comment: The separate class is where I use the top seller's sales and apply a commission to find the total compensation for that year, then compare it to the other salespersons total compensation and tell them how much more they need to sell in order to match the top seller's compensation.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in a different class?

Comment: I tried to do it in the same class but different method but the getters were not working. I have researched how to pass arrays to methods but  none of the things I came across worked. Forgive me I am pretty new to Java so there is a lot I still don't understand.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html I seriously recommend you check this out. You have a fundamental lack of understanding of how Java works.

Comment: Is there anywhere in particular that I should look at to help me understand what I am doing wrong? I understand some of the stuff but not everything. like I said I am pretty new to this like 3 weeks of doing it and I am sure that everyone on here is a lot more experienced than I am. I was just looking for help in understanding what I am doing wrong and why it is wrong. Help understanding is what I am looking for like what are the steps I need to take to help pass the values to the other class. Look at this section of the oracle tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating the array inside a static method you can make it a member of `EmployeeArray` you can then reuse the the array in a static context (not recommended) or create different `EmployeeArray`s to hold different arrays of employees, this makes more sense in OOP. A rough sketch:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmployeeArray {
private Employee[] employees;

public Employee[] getEmployees() {
    return employees;
}

public void setUpArray() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int numEmp;
    System.out.println("Enter how may employees to be compared: ");
    numEmp = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    employees = new Employee[numEmp];

    for (int i = 0; i < numEmp; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        String employeeName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter your annual sales: ");
        int employeeSales = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.println();

        Employee employee = new Employee(employeeName, employeeSales);
        employees[i] = employee;
    }
}

public int getMaxSellerEmployeeSales() {
    Employee maxSeller = employees[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {

        System.out.println("Employee Name: " + employees[i].getName());
        System.out.println("Total sales: $" + employees[i].getSales());
        System.out.println();

        if (maxSeller.getSales() < employees[i].getSales()) {
            maxSeller = employees[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Top Seller is: " + maxSeller.getName());
    System.out.println("Top Sales are: $" + maxSeller.getSales());
    return maxSeller.getSales();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EmployeeArray google = new EmployeeArray();
    google.setUpArray();

    EmployeeArray ms = new EmployeeArray();
    ms.setUpArray();

    EmployeeArrayCalculatorAndManipulator eGoogle = new EmployeeArrayCalculatorAndManipulator();
    EmployeeArrayCalculatorAndManipulator eMS = new EmployeeArrayCalculatorAndManipulator();
    eGoogle.doSomethingWithArray(google.getEmployees());
    eMS.doSomethingWithArray(ms.getEmployees());
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked out for me:-

package EmployeePackage;

public class Employee {

```
private int sales;
private String name;

public Employee(String employeeName, int employeeSales){
    this.name = employeeName;
    this.sales = employeeSales;


}
public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}
public int getSales(){
    return this.sales;
}
```

}

---

package EmployeePackage;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class EmployeeArray {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int numEmp;

    System.out.println("Enter how may employees to be compared: ");
    numEmp = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    Employee[] employees = new Employee[numEmp];

    for (int i = 0; i < numEmp; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        String employeeName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter your annual sales: ");
        int employeeSales = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.println();

 employees[i] = new Employee(employeeName , employeeSales); //calling constructor

    }
    Employee maxSeller = employees[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {

        System.out.println("Employee Name: " + employees[i].getName());
        System.out.println("Total sales: $" + employees[i].getSales());
        System.out.println();

        if (maxSeller.getSales() < employees[i].getSales()) {
            maxSeller = employees[i];
        }
    } 
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Top Seller is: " + maxSeller.getName());
    System.out.println("Top Sales are: $" + maxSeller.getSales());


}
```

}